# Resize Bitmap on Blackberry, while keeping alpha data

Tags: java, api, blackberry, image-processing

I have a source image in PNG with alpha information, that I scale with Graphics.scaleInto():

```
Bitmap dst = new Bitmap(123, 178);
dst.createAlpha(Bitmap.ALPHA_BITDEPTH_8BPP);
Bitmap img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(name);
img.scaleInto(dst, Bitmap.FILTER_BOX);
```

This works, the new scaled image is put in `dst`, but the alpha information is distorted. Some areas show as white, while some are transparent. Transparency borders have a blue tint to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you draw the scaled image?   As I found in [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239553/scale-a-bitmap-and-preserve-alpha-on-blackberry/4299740), even if you are doing the scaling correctly with respect to alpha, you need to call a drawing method that makes use of the alpha - Graphics.drawARGB().