# How do I make my custom bitmap button field use a transparent background?

Tags: java, blackberry, bitmap, transparent, buttonfield

I have a custom bitmap buttonfield that completely works, however, the background behind the image is showing a white rectangle. I've found where it makes the color white, but I cannot figure out how to make it completely transparent. Any ideas? I'm programming in blackberry java JDE 5.0

FYI The button image is a rounded corner png file that uses transparency on the corners

Code:

```
public class BitmapButtonField extends Field 
{

    Bitmap _currentPicture;
    private Bitmap _onPicture;
    Bitmap _offPicture;
    private int id;


    public BitmapButtonField (Bitmap  onImage, Bitmap offImage)
    {
       super(Field.FOCUSABLE|Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
       _offPicture = offImage;
       _onPicture = onImage;
       _currentPicture = _onPicture;
    }

    public void setButtonImage (Bitmap onImage, Bitmap offImage)
    {
        _offPicture = offImage;
        _onPicture = onImage;
        _currentPicture = _onPicture;
     }

    public void setButtonId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getButtonId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }    

    public int getPreferredHeight()
    {
        return _onPicture.getHeight();
    }


    public int getPreferredWidth()
    {
        return _onPicture.getWidth();
    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction)
    {
        _currentPicture = _offPicture;
       invalidate();
    }

    protected void onUnfocus()
    {
        _currentPicture = _onPicture;
       invalidate();
    }

    protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on)
    {        
        g.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setExtent(Math.min( width, getPreferredWidth()), Math.min( 
                            height, getPreferredHeight()));
    }

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
          int prevColor = g.getColor();
          int prevAlpha = g.getGlobalAlpha();
          g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
          g.setGlobalAlpha(0);
          g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // or g.getClippingRect()
          g.setColor(prevColor);
          g.setGlobalAlpha(prevAlpha);
        }

        protected void paint (Graphics graph){

        graph.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //super.paint(graph);

        graph.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graph.drawBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 
                             _currentPicture, 0, 0);    
        }


    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
    {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time)
    {
        if (key == Characters.ENTER)
        {
            fieldChangeNotify(0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have implemented `protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on)` and `protected void paintBackground(Graphics g)`. And you have also specified the background image for focused state. You can remove the implementation of `paintBackground` and `drawFocus`. Also the line which set the graphics color to white and fills a rectangle can be deleted from the method `paint`. That is you need to only paint the bitmap image on the `paint` method. I have modified your code here, http://pastebin.com/g9n8bqYc. You can check that (I didn't test it).

Comment: Rupak that worked perfectly! Thanks so much man. I'm trying to give you kudos here but its not letting me:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented

```
protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on)
```

and

```
protected void paintBackground(Graphics g)
```

And you have also specified the background image for focused state. You can remove the implementation of `paintBackground()` and `drawFocus()`. Also the line which set the graphics color to white and fills a rectangle can be deleted from the method paint. That is you need to only paint the bitmap image on the paint method. I have modified your code [here](http://pastebin.com/g9n8bqYc.), You can check that (I didn't test it).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your paint() method uses drawARGB to draw the bitmap on screen.  I had a similar problem, ["Scale a Bitmap and preserve alpha, on BlackBerry"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239553/scale-a-bitmap-and-preserve-alpha-on-blackberry), and it turned out that drawRGB and drawBitmap don't make use of the alpha channel, so won't leave anything transparent.

Comment: I'm not using drawRGB though, I'll post my code so you can get a better idea of what I'm using:

Comment: You're using 'graph.drawBitmap(...)' which I believe ultimately uses drawRGB.  You need to implement the pixel drawing directly - use getARGB(...) on the bitmap, and then use graph.drawARGB(...)

Comment: @MichaelDonohue, normally If I use a transparent PNG image, the `drawBitmap` method works well and handles alpha channel information while drawing. Also the method works if I manipulate the data (transparency) of the image (through `getARGB()` and `setARGB()`).

Answer (score 0):

your are using

```
graph.setColor(Color.WHITE);

 graph.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

method in your code (in paint() and paintBackground() method) which will create a white rectangle.

I think you need to remove this code.

if you still not able to find issue then i will provide another Custom BitmapField example.